# Creating SEO friendly urls using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo

I am trying to rewrite the urls of a site, i should mention that the way index.php works now is getting the p (page) parameter and including the appropriate file.

So requesting a page is like this:

```
www.domain.com/index.php?p=home
www.domain.com/index.php?p=search
www.domain.com/index.php?p=profile
www.domain.com/index.php?p=contact
```

I found how to create a rewrite rule for this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1
```

so now **www.domain.com/home** would give me the home page

But i also need to have a friendly url for this

```
www.domain.com/index.php?p=profile&id=20

to

www.domain.com/profile/20/profile-friendly-name

or better

www.domain.com/profile/profile-friendly-name
```

*The profile-friendly-name refers to a company name

Requirements:

1. To have friendly urls for all pages e.g. /home, /contact
2. To have a particular friendly url for the profile page with the
   profile name in the url

My questions:

1. How can i add a profile-friendly-name to the url with the existing url format (index.php?p=profile&id=20)?
2. Can i only have a unique name there (without the id), like my last
   example?
3. If i manage to do that, will i have to change ALL the existing urls
   within the site (links, urls to images, to files) to the friendly
   format?
4. I noticed that after applying the first RewriteRule some css
   stylesheets and js are not included. What is wrong?

Comment: Better not to ask too many questions in one post

Comment: you should look in to an MVC framework instead of htaccess for SEO friendly urls.

Comment: Yes i know @anubhava but i am confused...

Comment: I can't use an MVC, i can't change the structure of the website right now as it is a big project

Comment: From where are you going to get `/profile-friendly-name`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=profile&id=$1
```

Should work for :

```
www.domain.com/index.php?p=profile&id=20

to

www.domain.com/profile/20/profile-friendly-name
```

Comment: So i just echo the profile's name to a url for a link (after the id) and only use the id to get the profile information?

Comment: After adding the rule, all urls in www.domain.com/profile/<id here>/profile-friendly-name format should work...

Comment: This is a very helpful solution.

Answer (score 4):

Ex 1 :
`https://example.com/books.php?bookName=php`  using  htaccess  url will be written like this `https://example.com/php`

You can do this using code given below in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ books.php?bookName=$1
```

Ex 2 :

`https://example.com/books.php?bookName=php&&chapter=array`   using  htaccess  url will be written like
`https://example.com/php/array`

You can get by using code in `.htaccess` file given below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ books.php?bookName=$1&chapter=$2
```