# Remove .php extention from url working but seo friendly url not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to make seo friendly url using .htaccess.

I want to convert below url

```
http://localhost/projectname/pagename.php?id=1
```

to

```
http://localhost/projectname/pagename/1
```

I have already tried solution for this

```
RewriteRule ^pagename/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ projectname/pagename.php?id=$1
```

But it's not working

I have also referred below links but not giving me right solution

[How to write htaccess rewrite rule for seo friendly url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168375/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-seo-friendly-url)

[Creating SEO friendly urls using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285463/creating-seo-friendly-urls-using-htaccess)

.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

 RewriteRule ^pagename/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ projectname/pagename.php?id=$1

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

using above htaccess file I can remove `.php` extention from url but not to generate seo friendly url.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: you can use [AltoRouter](http://altorouter.com/) for doing this.

Comment: without altorouter by making function and calling function I can easily convert url but I want to achieve it using .htacesss that's why I asked

Answer (score 0):

You have a slash at the end of your rule, so you would have to go:

```
http://localhost/projectname/pagename/1/
```

Or change the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^pagename/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ projectname/pagename.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Where is your htaccess file stored?  Try doing ^projectname/pagename/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$

Comment: changed the rule which u have provided but it converts url to projectname/pagename?id=$1